# Can't update values in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Username doesn't get updated after running this. I also tried UpdateOne and it didn't work as well. The code was supposed to update an array but I tried updating the username to make it easier to track down the problem.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new schema({
    Username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Cart: Array
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

.

```
app.post('/putbox', (req, res) => {


    var query = { Username: user };

    var newvalues = { $push: { Cart: "Boxing" } };

    try{

        User.find(query).then((d)=>{

            var values = d[0].Cart;
            values.push("boxing")

            User.findByIdAndUpdate(d._id, {Username: "test1"})

        });

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 

    res.redirect('/boxing');

});
```

Comment: Do you plan to store the password as clear text?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax is not correct. The first element of `updateOne` searches for matches to update. You are just passing `d._id` which is not the same as the `_id` key in your db structure. Try this one

```
User.updateOne({ _id: d._id }, {Username: "test1"})
```